# Google Anytics without javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics, measurement-protocol

We want to track the `utm_source` and `utm_medium` on Google Analytics on one of our clients site. We also want to get the conversion of the ad.

We can:

```
ga('send', 'pageview');  //Using our tracking number
```

This would work perfectly but our client will no allow js code added. We are thinking of using `http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif` but according to [doc](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingTroubleshooting?csw=1#gifParameters), `utmcc` should pass the cookie values.

Is there any way we can use `utm.gif` with **static** parameter values?

```
<img src="http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?....">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [email tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/email) it works though the measurement protocol which is the same as the JavaScript library uses.

```
<img src="https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&..."/>
```

You can build up the hits as you wish.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Im wondering on how can we track the conversion?

Comment: I mean, I have to specify the campaign on the URL of the image based on the doc. How can we detect that the user on `thankyou.html` entered (from a different page) using `utm_source` and `utm_medium`?

Comment: you can add campaign tracking to the image https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#trafficsources

Comment: I can't seem to make this work `<img src="https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-XXXX-X&t=pageview"/>`. I can see 0 active users on site

Comment: Did you read the documentation on email tracking that i linked?  it states that cid is required.